# While loop not quitting

Tags: c#

My program is supposed to calculate the miles per gallon for a trip.

The program runs fine until I try to quit when I'm inside the loop. It's supposed to quit when the user types in *"quit"* at any point in the three inputs but it just goes to the next input. Even when I type in quit in all three inputs, it just crashes.

Things I've tried:

- Typing quit in all three inputs
- Using only 1 condition for the loop instead or three
- Putting strBeginningOdometerReading.ToUpper() != 1-10000000
- Changing all the || to &&
- Changing QUIT to a string variable

```cs
using System;

namespace MPG
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Declare the variables
            string strBeginningOdometerReading, strEndingOdometerReading, strNumberOfGallons;
            double dblBeginningOdometerReading, dblEndingOdometerReading, dblNumberOfGallons, dblMilesPerGallon, dblMilesTravelled;

            //Priming prompt & read
            Console.Write("Enter the beginning odometer reading: ");
            strBeginningOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the ending odometer reading: ");
            strEndingOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the number of gallons purchased for six fill-ups during the trip.");
            strNumberOfGallons = Console.ReadLine();

            //Convert
            dblBeginningOdometerReading = Convert.ToDouble(strBeginningOdometerReading);
            dblEndingOdometerReading = Convert.ToDouble(strEndingOdometerReading);
            dblNumberOfGallons = Convert.ToDouble(strNumberOfGallons);

            //Calculations
            dblMilesTravelled = dblEndingOdometerReading - dblBeginningOdometerReading;
            dblMilesPerGallon = dblMilesTravelled / dblNumberOfGallons;

            //Display
            Console.WriteLine("Miles Travelled: \t\t\t {0:n2} miles", dblMilesTravelled);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons Purchased for 6 fill-ups: {0:n2} gallons", dblNumberOfGallons);
            Console.WriteLine("Miles per Gallon (MPG): \t\t\t {0:n2} mpg", dblMilesPerGallon);

            //While loop
            while (strBeginningOdometerReading.ToUpper() != "QUIT" || strEndingOdometerReading.ToUpper() != "QUIT" || strNumberOfGallons.ToUpper() != "QUIT")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter QUIT at any time to exit.");
                Console.Write("Enter the beginning odometer reading: ");
                strBeginningOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter the ending odometer reading: ");
                strEndingOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter the number of gallons purchased for six fill-ups during the trip: ");
                strNumberOfGallons = Console.ReadLine();

                //Convert
                dblBeginningOdometerReading = Convert.ToDouble(strBeginningOdometerReading);
                dblEndingOdometerReading = Convert.ToDouble(strEndingOdometerReading);
                dblNumberOfGallons = Convert.ToDouble(strNumberOfGallons);

                //Calculations
                dblMilesTravelled = dblEndingOdometerReading - dblBeginningOdometerReading;
                dblMilesPerGallon = dblMilesTravelled / dblNumberOfGallons;

                //Display
                Console.WriteLine("Miles Travelled: \t\t\t {0:n2} miles", dblMilesTravelled);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons Purchased for 6 fill-ups: {0:n2} gallons", dblNumberOfGallons);
                Console.WriteLine("Miles per Gallon (MPG): \t\t\t {0:n2} mpg", dblMilesPerGallon);
            } // end while
        } //end Main
    } //end class
} //end namespace
```

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP EVERYONE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strBeginningOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();` is inside the while loop, so expect the rest of the codes in the while to be executed untill the next loop.

You can perhaps add `if(strBeginningOdometerReading.ToUpper() =="QUIT") break;` right after `strBeginningOdometerReading = Console.ReadLine();`  to break out of the while loop and stop executing the rest of the codes.

And change to `while(true)` and u'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition should be AND

```
(strBeginningOdometerReading.ToUpper() != "QUIT" && strEndingOdometerReading.ToUpper() != "QUIT" && strNumberOfGallons.ToUpper() != "QUIT")
```